# How to fix 'JSONDecodeError' which occurs because of reading image from URL during conversion to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, urllib, pyinstaller

I'm using Tkinter in python to read an image from a URL and extract the text using Tesseract-OCR and display it on a Tkinter canvas. The project is almost complete, but when I try to convert the python file to a .exe file, JSONDecodeError pops up. The code works perfectly fine until I run it using IDLE.

I tried using requests to get the URL and read the image, but I was unable to do so. and hence I used 'urllib.request.urlopen(url)'. But during conversion to .exe using pyinstaller, 'JSONDecodeError' pops up and the conversion stops. Pyinstaller used to convert the .py file to a .exe file before I put the module (the one to read an image from URL).
How do I solve this?

Here is a small part of the code:

```
import urllib.request

if url=="":
    tk.messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Enter a URL!!!")
img=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
self.tesseract(Image.open(img),root)
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
  File "c:\users\aayush.gour\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-pac
kages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py", line 23, in <module>
    collect_system_data_files(pyqt5_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],
  File "c:\users\aayush.gour\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-pac
kages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 67, in __getattr__
    qli = json.loads(json_str)
  File "c:\users\aayush.gour\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\__i
nit__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\aayush.gour\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\dec
oder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\aayush.gour\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\json\dec
oder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I found the answer to my own question.
The answer to this question is in 2 parts.

Part 1

Instead of using `urllib.request`, I used `io` from `skimage` library. It was much easier. Here is the code (I use Python 3.6.8)

```
from skimage import io
url="https://SomeUrlForAnImage.com"
img=io.imread(url)
self.tesseract(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), root)
```

I used the `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` function to convert the image from BGR to RGB color coding.

Part 2 - Updating Pyinstaller

If you used `pip install pyinstaller` to install pyinstaller, then uninstall it using `pip uninstall pyinstaller` and install the latest version from [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller). Download the zip file and extract it using WinRar or any other software like 7z. Open the command window in the extracted folder and type `python setup.py install`. This will install the latest version of pyinstaller on your device. Most of the errors can be eliminated by installing the latest version of pyinstaller itself.